# What are the shortcuts keys for Netbeans code folding?

Tags: netbeans

Does anybody know a shortcut to fold/unfold (collapse/expand) all classes/methods in a php file using netbeans?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**To Collapse:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Minus</kbd> (on the keypad)

**To Expand:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Plus</kbd> (on the keypad)

This works regardless of what language your using, (Tested on PHP, HTML, CSS & Javascript)

But you can find out the keyboard shortcuts easily yourself, and even change them:

- Open the Options Dialog (Tools -> Options)
- Then Select Keymap
- Enter "`Collapse`" into the input field labelled "`Search`" and all shortcuts for that action are displayed. You can do the same for "`Expand All`"

Comment: Thanks that was working! Assuming that I'm using mac it's command-shift-plus

Comment: additional tip: if you only want to fold or collapse the current function / method based on your current cursor position, use Ctrl+Minus (keypad) src: http://ui.netbeans.org/docs/ui/code_folding/cf_uispec.html#actions

Comment: Tip: if you use Ctrl+Shift+Minus, it collapses the class block too (if you have a class, of course). If you want to see just the methods collapsed, you just have the work of expand the class block, and all methods will be already collapsed.

Comment: How to expand all for/while/if folds within a function/method?

Comment: You can also create custom inline code folds using the <editor-fold> tags inside your code.
Check here for details: 
http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqCustomCodeFolds

Answer (score 0):

I found the **Collapse All** function to be a pain because it even collapses the nested blocks inside of your methods. There seems to be no collapse methods shortcut.

If you are like me and just want the methods and comments collapsed by default this can be configured in the preferences.

Under **Editor->Folding** in your **Preferences** click on the language dropdown and select **PHP**.

- Check the '**Functions and methods**' checkbox.
- Check the '**PHPDoc documentation**' checkbox.

This will probably yield the result you are looking for.

I also like to uncheck the '**Show summary**' checkbox to reduce visual noise.

You can still use the **Expand All** shortcut key as described in the other post if you wish to see everything.